# Filter NSDictionary that in other NSDictionary

Tags: ios, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary with children in other dictionaries extracted from a parsing JSON.
The structure looks like this:

```
    {
        children =             (
                            {
                children =                     (
                                            {
                        hasArticles = 1;
                        hasWideIcon = 0;
                        label = biological;
                        urlId = 9950000123891;
                    },
                                            {
                        hasArticles = 1;
                        hasWideIcon = 0;
                        label = White;
                        urlId = 9950000123892;
                    },
                                            {
                        hasArticles = 1;
                        hasWideIcon = 0;
                        label = "various flavors";
                        urlId = 9950000123893;
                    },
                                            {
                        hasArticles = 1;
                        hasWideIcon = 0;
                        label = "different tastes creamy";
                        urlId = 9950000123894;
                    },
                                            {
                        hasArticles = 1;
                        hasWideIcon = 0;
                        label = "yogurt drinks";
                        urlId = 9950000123895;
                    },
                                            {
                        hasArticles = 1;
                        hasWideIcon = 0;
                        label = "Yogurt mix";
                        urlId = 9950000123896;
                    },
                                            {

                );
                hasArticles = 0;
                hasWideIcon = 0;
                label = "types of yogurt"; //those above are the children of the "types of yogurt" 
                urlId = 9950000123890;
            },


                            {
                children =                     (
                                            {
                        hasArticles = 1;
                        hasWideIcon = 0;
                        label = White;
                        urlId = 9950000123906;
                    },
                                            {
                        hasArticles = 1;
                        hasWideIcon = 0;
                        label = "various flavors";
                        urlId = 9950000123907;
                    },

                                            {
                        hasArticles = 1;
                        hasWideIcon = 0;
                        label = Pappareale;
                        urlId = 9950000123909;
                    }
                );
                hasArticles = 0;
                hasWideIcon = 0;
                label = "yogurt healthy"; //those above are the children of the yogurt healthy 
                urlId = 9950000123905;
            },

                            {
                hasArticles = 1;
                hasWideIcon = 0;
                label = "puddings and creams";
                urlId = 9950000123911;
            },
                            {
                hasArticles = 1;
                hasWideIcon = 0;
                label = "Snack dessert";
                urlId = 9950000123913;
            },
                            {
                hasArticles = 1;
                hasWideIcon = 0;
                label = "various Dessert";
                urlId = 9950000123914;
            }
        );
        hasArticles = 0;
        hasWideIcon = 0;
        label = "Yogurt and Dessert ";
        urlId = 9950000123889;
    },
```

My code

```
 -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

        NSLog(@"%d", [webData length]);

       NSString *strResult =[[NSString alloc]initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       NSDictionary *result =[strResult JSONValue];
           for (id obj in result){
                  NSLog(@"%@", result);
                  /*A part of the result is written above, but in reality is much 
                    longer and includes all possible products in a supermarket*/

           }

   }
```

How do I extract the children of "yogurtDessert" that are

- Types of yogurt (who has children)
- yogurt-healty (who has children)
- pudding and creams (without children)
- Snack dessert (without children)
- various desserts (without children)

How do I extract then to the children of the children of yogurtDessert not knowing in advance?

I need to create an array of dictionaries containing the categories of products in a supermarket (in this example there is only yogurt and dessert, a total of 23 elements), then I have to create another array of dictionaries each containing subcategories of each product, that are thousands. I thought about using NSPredicate but are dictionaries.
I have to filter a dictionary in other dictionaries

Comment: hello confusing what you want exactly ?

Comment: How do you want to present this structure in UI? You can still use NSPredicate to filter out using the "urlId". But it would be better if you can create a custom class like "Category".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hierarchy of dictionaries seems to contain two types of dictionaries: Those that represent a category and those that are products.

I'm guessing here that leaf dictionaries (without children) are always products. Dictionaries that have the children key are always categories. That might not be true—it looks like `hasArticles` is 1 for products, 0 for categories—but again, that's unknown.

Here's code that extracts all products:

```
static void collectProducts(NSDictionary *dictionary, NSMutableArray *results)
{
    NSArray *children == dictionary[@"children"];

    if (children == nil) {
        [results addObject:dictionary];
        return;
    }

    for (NSDictionary *subDict in children)
        collectProducts(subDict, results);
}

NSArray *findProducts(NSDictionary *dictionary)
{
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    collectProducts(dictionary, result);
    return array;
}
```

Call `findProducts` with your JSON `result` to get all leaf dictionaries.